# Event "SelectedIndexChanged" is not found in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, combobox

in winform when i create a combobox i can found event "SelectedIndexChanged"
the event work **after** index of combobox changed

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("after index change app show this MessageBox ");
    }
```

but in wpf i cannot found event "SelectedIndexChanged"
instead of i can found event "SelectionChanged"
but i have  a problem when is use it  before index of combobox event work but i want to after index change show my code in event "SelectionChanged"

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("before index change app show this MessageBox ");
    }
```

what should i do . i want to show my MessageBox after i change index of my combobox

sry for my poor english

Answer (score 5):

Actually The event 'SelectionChanged' is called after index and value are changed you can check it simple

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string[] _cmbxSource = new string[] {
            "ZeroIndex",
            "FirstIndex"
        };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cmbx.ItemsSource = _cmbxSource;

        cmbx.SelectionChanged += cmbx_SelectionChanged;
    }

    void cmbx_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Value and Index has been changed {0} {1}",
            _cmbxSource[cmbx.SelectedIndex], cmbx.SelectedIndex));
    }
}
```