# Catching input events

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a form with `TextBox`, `ComboBox` and `CheckBox` that are filled from a function (with `textbox.text = "newValue";` for example).

```
private void updateIdentite(Contact c, Dal dal)
{
    Identite id = dal.GetIdentite(c);
    if (id != null)
    {
        idCivilite.SelectedValue = id.type_civilite;//example of a ComboBox
        ...
        idNom.Text = id.pers_nom;//example of a TextBox
        ...
        idAi.IsChecked = (id.cont_drap_ai == "1");//example of a CheckBox
        ...
    }
}
```

I need to catch an event when an item is edited manually by the user, but with `TextChanged`, `SelectionChanged` or `Checked`, these events are also fired when the form is filled with the previous function.

```
foreach (object item in identiteGrid.Children)
{
    TextBox tb = item as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        tb.TextChanged += new TextChangedEventHandler(idTextBox_TextChanged);
        continue;
    }
    ComboBox droplist = item as ComboBox;
    if (droplist != null)
    {
        droplist.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(idCombobox_SelectionChanged);
        continue;
    }
    CheckBox cb = item as CheckBox;
    if (cb != null)
    {
        cb.Checked += new RoutedEventHandler(idCheckbox_Checked);
        continue;
    } 
}
```

Is there any way to catch an "onInput" event for those controls ?

Thanks

Comment: What does "when the form is filled with the previous function" mean? Which "previous function" are you referring to?

Comment: @mm8 "that are filled from a function (with `textbox.text = "newValue"; for example)"

Comment: @mm8 Really not necessary but edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either hook up your event handlers, i.e. execute the foreach loop, *after* you have set initial values.

Or you could temporarily unhook the event handlers just before you programmatically set the values:

```
private void updateIdentite(Contact c, Dal dal)
{
    Identite id = dal.GetIdentite(c);
    if (id != null)
    {
        idCivilite.SelectionChanged -= idCombobox_SelectionChanged;
        idCivilite.SelectedValue = id.type_civilite;//example of a ComboBox
        idCivilite.SelectionChanged += idCombobox_SelectionChanged;

        tb.TextChanged -= idTextBox_TextChanged;
        idNom.Text = id.pers_nom;//example of a TextBox
        tb.TextChanged += idTextBox_TextChanged;

        idAi.Checked -= idCheckbox_Checked;
        idAi.IsChecked = (id.cont_drap_ai == "1");//example of a CheckBox
        idAi.Checked += idCheckbox_Checked;
    }
}
```

Or you could use a boolean flag to prevent the code inside the event handler from being run in specific cases:

```
private bool handleSelectionChanged = true;
private void updateIdentite(Contact c, Dal dal)
{
    ...
    handleSelectionChanged = false;
    idCivilite.SelectedValue = id.type_civilite;//example of a ComboBox
    handleSelectionChanged = true;
    ...
}

private void idCombobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!handleSelectionChanged)
        return;

    //your code...
}
```

Comment: I'll take it for the boolean flag idea (I already came up with this "temporary" solution), but thank you, have my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

### Grabbing User Input

Consider using: `Control.OnKeyDown` Method.

in order to place input **by the user** he must be with focus on the control and hit some key.

Also , if you want to be fully covered you can also hook `Control.MouseClick` Event on the controls...

Read more on these events.

---

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onkeydown(v=vs.110).aspx

---

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I thought of this solution but does this work with `ComboBox` for `MouseClick` event ? If the user just click on the `ComboBox` without changing the selected item, it shouldn't fire an event

Comment: i added the MouseClick mostly for user trying to paste info using the Mouse only (RightKey-> Paste). thats not common. so if you want to hook to this event consider checking inside the function what mosue key was clicked. on combobox consider hooking to SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: Also, `SelectedIndexChanged` does not exist in WPF.

Comment: SelectedIndexChanged in WPF ->> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374316/event-selectedindexchanged-is-not-found-in-wpf